# Unknown error in playing a stream (http/rtsp) using Android Media Player

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I am using Android Media Player to play a music stream from a provided rtsp or http server. I can easily play a http stream (for example from soundcloud) or from a rtsp stream found on the  internet. But my player cannot play neither from our http server nor from the rtsp server. The error for rtsp is : error (1, -2147483648). Based on Android Audio Manager, that code (-2147483648 (0x80000000)) refers to USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE which indicates :"Suggests using the default stream type. This may not be used in all places a stream type is needed."
And error for http server is : error (1, -1010). 
I just simply start my player like this:

```
  String url = "rtsp://******/***.mp3"; // My url is with this format
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  
  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

    }
  });               
  try {
       mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(url));
       mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```